# Java Queue can't store Integer in this case

Tags: java

```
Queue<Integer>[] queues = new Queue[3];
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    queues[i] = new LinkedList<Integer>();
}
Queue thisqueue = queues[1];
while(thisqueue.peek()<10) {}
```

This is my java code. when I run this code the eclipse tell me `The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) Object, int`

I can't understand I store everything in queue as Integer why it become object when I use `peek()`.

How to fix this? I want to peek the tail number as int and compare with 10.

Comment: Because you're using a raw type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told the compiler what type of objects `thisqueue` holds.  Try replacing:

```
Queue thisqueue = queues[1];
```

with

```
Queue<Integer>  thisqueue = queues[1];
```